# How do you set the targetPath of jar overlay in a war?

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I was reading [the war plugin's overlay documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) and it said:

> **targetPath** - the target relative path in the webapp structure, which is only available for overlays of type war. By default, the content of the overlay is added in the root structure of the webapp.

But I'm trying to overlay a jar, not a war.  I don't want the files to be at the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Turns out that documentation is wrong and you can use a **targetPath** with a type, `jar`.

Comment: What about making a JIRA issue about what you have found? issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR ?

Comment: @khmarbaise i looked for this, but it was very difficult to google for.

Comment: If you take on the plugin page: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/issue-tracking.html  for every plugin you will find the appropriate link. For every plugin from Apache Maven: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/ ...