# How to set a WAR overlay targetPath for ZIP overlay?

Tags: java, maven, war

In a java project, I have a ZIP overlay that I'd like to set the `targetPath` for.  The docs say only WAR is supported, not ZIP.  [How do you set the targetPath of jar overlay in a war?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895963/how-do-you-set-the-targetpath-of-jar-overlay-in-a-war) indicates that JAR is also supported.  Regardless, I've tested the ZIP and targetPath in the POM seems to be ignored.

Is there a way to set the targetPath for a ZIP overlay?

### UPDATE

To clarify:

1. The WAR overlay serves content as `/X...'
2. I want it served as `/abc/X...`
3. I thought the way to do that was via `targetPath`
4. If there's another way to do it, please let me know

### UPDATE 2

I'm including a WAR as an overlay.  It works fine.  It serves `"http://myapp.com/x/y/z.js"` beautifully.

But, I'd like it to serve that same content at `"http://myapp.com/MYPREFIX/x/y/z.js"`.

Comment: First why not using the war as overlay which works? Maybe I misunderstand your question?...

Comment: @khmarbaise Clarified

Comment: Hm...can you give a more concrete example of what your problem is? It looks like you need a rename?

Answer (score 0):

If it’s just the one prefix path, you should be able to use the web context for that. Almost all war deployment environments I’ve worked with support it - even spring boot. 
What web server is it being deployed under?

Comment: Jetty.  To be clear, I can control the context for _my app_; I want to be able to control it for the overlay I'm adding in as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate or give an example? As the question stated, I haven't been able to get this to work.